# ListView's ItemSelected event is not firing when list item is a SwipeView wrapped inside a ContentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tested SwipeView's functionalities perfectly with a ListView.
But when I wrapped it inside a ContentView, swipe actions are working but ListView's ItemSelected event is not firing.

Sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="EmployeeView"
              ItemSelected="EmployeeView_ItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ContentView>
                            <SwipeView>
                                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                        <SwipeItem Text="Favorite"
                                               BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
                                        <SwipeItem Text="Delete"
                                               BackgroundColor="LightPink" />
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         BackgroundColor="GreenYellow">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Age}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </SwipeView>
                        </ContentView>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I'm using XF 5.0.0.2012 and only tested with Android.

In my real requirement I'm using a grouped ListView where most of the groups don't need swipe actions.
When list items count getting larger observed some lags in Swipe items loading. Therefor thought to use the SwipeView only if needed else using a read only Grid. So planned to set the ContentView   based on a Trigger.

Comment: Should be fixed as [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9466)

Comment: @Shaw Hmm, unfortunately not as I am on XF 5.0.0.2012.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but instead of attempting to modify ContentView of individual items via trigger, maybe use `DataTemplateSelector`? That avoids need to have `ContentView`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks for the suggestion which is working great with this scenario. But will keep this open as original issue exists.

Comment: But its no longer an issue for you, right? If I understand everything you've said, the problem happens when ListView > ContentView > SwipeView. So remove ContentView, it works? (If so, then title needs to be adjusted to indicate ContentView is a factor.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Agreed, changed the title.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with ListView, but same scenario works fine with CollectionView.